# Pyspark: How to control which nodes jobs run on?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running some analyses on a Spark cluster which is exhibiting some strange behavior - a few of the 20+ nodes will occasionally become unresponsive. We're working on figuring out the cause of this, but I'm also desperate for a workaround when this happens.

Say I learn that the node *foo* is unresponsive, and want to run my job on all other nodes. I want to do something like

```
sc = SparkContext()
sc.exclude_nodes(["foo"])
```

in my script (that I submit with spark-submit).

Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

What is the master you use when you use to submit the spark job
if it is

{-- master yarn}

> YARN

then I will suggest you to check the status of the job in Yarn UI and see what is the issue?

(1) Check what is the status of your job in Yarn ?(it is submitted, failed or running)
    you may find some errors there.

Comment: I don't know. I simply run jobs with spark-submit filename.py.